# grails internationalization messages hot deployment not working in dev

Tags: grails, deployment, internationalization

I have a strange issue while running an app in dev mode. The messages_*.properties are not hot deployed. This is very weird since it used to work in older versions now with version 2.2.1 doesnt work anymore.

Does anyone also have this issue? Any idea how to solve it?

Thanks,
Regards,
Nicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade grails version to solve it. it is a [**bug**](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9898)
Otherwise you can use workaround in comments to ticket from **dongheping**, but I recommend upgrade